# How to wrap one div id around another one?

Tags: html, css

How to wrap one div around another? I have following two `div` ids:

```css
#course {
  width: 325px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

#home-page-sign-up {
  width: 275px;
  #padding-left: 25px;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  #position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

I want `#course` to be on left and `#home-page-sign-up` on right just next to it. I do get block on left and right as assigned but one is below another, I want them to be side by side.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: `float: right;` is good, but you need to put the `#home-page-sign-up`    div before the `#course` div in the html

Comment: Dear see  my answer and let me know if anything else you want. I create html structure as per your requirement see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to float both of them left:

```
#course{
    float:left;
    width:325px;
    padding-right:25px;
    border-right:1px solid #999;
    border-top:1px solid #999;
}

#home-page-sign-up {
    width:275px;
    #padding-left:25px;
    float:left;
    margin: auto; 
    #position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

Just make sure #course falls first in the html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#course{
width:325px;
float:left;
padding-right:25px;
border-right:1px solid #999;
border-top:1px solid #999;
}

#home-page-sign-up {
width:275px;
#padding-left:25px;
float:left;
margin: auto; 
#position:relative;
}
```

Then, in your body tags, do:

```
<div id="course">Course Div Content here...</div>
<div id="home-page-sign-up">Home Sign-up Content here...</div>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

That's one way...that hopefully works ;)

Comment: this works great! but now I have this inheritance big-container > container > course and home-page-sign-up. Course is overflowing big-container and container. how do I solve that?

Comment: Solved! I mistakenly put `</div>` at wrong place. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean by "wrap around" but if you want the divs to be next to each other, put float: left; in both styles...

Answer (score 0):

see fiddle for code and demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4LUF/3/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t4LUF/3/embedded/result/

NOTE: For demo purpose i gave border to all div's you can change as per your need.

HTML:

```
<div id="big-container">big-container
    <div id="container">
        <div id="course">course Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        <div id="home-page-sign-up">home-page-sign-up </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SS: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/3783/divcontainersidebyside.jpg